# Excel: How to use =SUM() with two strings for range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to pass in two strings indicating the two locations of the range. However, SUM wouldn't read the string, but it reads the value of what's supposed to be the indicator of a location.

What I wrote:

`=SUM(E20:E21)`

The value of `E20` is `E4`, and the value of `E21` is `E10`. They are both dynamically generated. How can I get the actual sum from the location that the value of `E20` indicates to the location that the value of `E21` indicates?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Look into `INDIRECT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261):

`=INDIRECT(E20&":"&E21)`

Comment: Tip: `=SUM( INDIRECT(E20 & ":" & E21) )`